# Discord bot running but commands are not responsive

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've created a Discord Bot which is very much running when started but the commands are not responsive. The code is below:

```
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is now running!!')

@client.event
async def hello_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
    if ctx.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await ctx.channel.send('Hello there!!!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

When executed - the bot shows up online and prints the running message. However, it is not responding to any commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `discord.Client` for commands:
In discord.py, you need to use the `commands.Bot` class instead of discord.Client to handle commands effectively. The `commands.Bot` class provides built-in command parsing and handling.

Using `on_ready()` for commands:
The `on_ready()` event is triggered when the bot is connected and ready to perform actions, but it is not meant to handle commands. You should use `commands.Bot` to handle commands separately.

Here is the updated code:

```py
    import os
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

    # Create the bot with the command prefix
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

# Event: Bot is ready
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{bot.user} is now running!!')

    # Command: Hello
    @bot.command()
    async def hello(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hello there!!!')

    # Run the bot
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: didn't enable intents, this will not work.